# qsort in C (dynamic allocation)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, qsort

I want to know this situation.

when I define this sentence

```
struct soccer team[100] ;
```

I can do qsort ;

```
qsort(team, MAX , sizeof(team[0]) , compare) ;
int compare(const void *a, const void *b ) 
{
   SOC *A1 =  (SOC*)a ; 
   SOC *B1 =  (SOC*)b ;

   if( A1->score > B1->score )
       return -1 ;
   else if ( A1->score == B1->score )
       return 0 ;
   else
       return 1 ;
}
```

When I do dynamic allocation

```
struct soccer*team[MAX] ;
team[Index] = (SOC*)malloc(sizeof(SOC)) ;
```

error is existed. (qsort and compare is same )

I want to know how do use it(qsort for dynamic allocation struct)

please!

example ( when I use first way)

```
Man 3 1 1 16
Che 2 2 2 8
Asn 0 6 0 6 
hot 6 0 0 18
City 0 0 6 0 
Bar 1 5 0 8
```

is converted

```
hot 6 0 0 18
Man 3 1 1 16
Che 2 2 2 8
Bar 1 5 0 8
Asn 0 6 0 6 
City 0 0 6 0
```

Comment: "qsort and compare is same" it is bad because the same comparision function shouldn't be used for different element type.

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: my misstake!

original code : typedef struct soccer SOC ;

Answer (score 1):

The first version

```
 struct soccer team[100] ;
```

and the second one

```
struct soccer*team[MAX] ;
team[Index] = (SOC*)malloc(sizeof(SOC)) ;
```

are not same. The first one is an array of `struct soccer` and the second one is an array of `struct soccer *`. They are not just the same.

If you want to use the later version (including pointer) and get the same behaviour as above, you can do something like

```
struct soccer * team;
team = malloc(sizeof *team * SIZE) ;  // SIZE is the number of elements
```

Comment: yes, I konw. I want to know using way when I  use qsort(dynamic allocation)

Comment: @CherubimAnand no, it's `sizeof *team`, check the data type.

Comment: @CherubimAnand right, but nothing stops you from writing `a = malloc(sizeof *a * SIZE));` and this is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

The same comparision function cannot be used for different element types. Use correct comparision function like this (pointers to elements, which are pointers, will be given, so dereference them to get the pointers to structs):

```
int compare2(const void *a, const void *b ) 
{
   SOC *A1 =  *(SOC**)a ;
   SOC *B1 =  *(SOC**)b ;

   if( A1->score > B1->score )
       return -1 ;
   else if ( A1->score == B1->score )
       return 0 ;
   else
       return 1 ;
}
```

Note: They say [you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: @박기현 Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to have us fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how a similar array can be sorted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX 10

typedef struct soccer
{
    unsigned int score;
} SOC;

int cmp( const void *a, const void *b )
{
    const SOC *lhs = *( const SOC ** )a;
    const SOC *rhs = *( const SOC ** )b;

    return ( lhs->score > rhs->score ) - ( rhs->score > lhs->score );
}

int main( void ) 
{
    SOC * team[MAX];

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    for ( int i = 0; i < MAX; i++ ) 
    {
        team[i] = malloc( sizeof( SOC ) );
        team[i]->score = rand() % MAX;
    }       

    for ( int i = 0; i < MAX; i++ ) 
    {
        printf( "%u ", team[i]->score );
    }
    printf( "\n" );

    qsort( team, MAX, sizeof( SOC * ), cmp );

    for ( int i = 0; i < MAX; i++ ) 
    {
        printf( "%u ", team[i]->score );
    }
    printf( "\n" );

    for ( int i = 0; i < MAX; i++ ) free( team[i] );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
2 7 2 5 1 6 1 5 0 4 
0 1 1 2 2 4 5 5 6 7
```

Comment: team[i] = malloc( sizeof( SOC ) ); -> is this type error?

Comment: @박기현 Did you try the program? What is wrong with this statement?

Comment: Error : a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "SOC *"

Comment: @박기현 You have to compile the program as a C-program while you are compiling the program as a C++ program. Otherwise you have to write team[I] = ( SOC * )malloc( sizeof( SOC ) );